# ArgumentException when creating instance of object that inherits from ObjectContext

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, constructor, objectcontext

I'm loosely following an [excellent series of blog posts by Kazi Manzur Rashid](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/09/13/shrinkr-url-shrinking-service-developed-with-entity-framework-4-0-unity-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery-part-2.aspx) as a learning exercise for learning how to implement some new (for me at least) design patterns, but I'm getting trouble from the start.

I've basically copied his code for the `Database`, `RepositoryBase` and `RepositoryBaseTests` classes, but when I try to run the tests, I get an error message saying

> Unable to create instance of class Booking.Infrastructure.EntityFramework.Repositories.Tests.RepositoryBaseTests. Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0..

Through the debugger I have verified that the exception is thrown on the constructor for the `Database` class, which looks like this:

```
public Database(
    IConfigurationManager configurationManager, 
    string connectionstringName)
: base(
    GetConnectionString(configurationManager, connectionstringName), 
    "BookingEntities")
{ // Nothing happens here }
```

The error is thrown when calling the `base` constructor, and if I'd hard-code the values that I'm currently sending in, it would look like this:

```
: base("Dummy connStr", "BookingEntities")
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Dummy connStr" is not a valid EF connection string.

A valid EF connection string looks like:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.Model.csdl|res://*/Data.Model.ssdl|res://*/Data.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=SERVERNAME\SQLDEV2008;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"
```

Comment: OK. Well, I could figure out that the connection string wouldn't be a valid one, but I assumed it *should* have worked anyway as it did in the example in the article. Anyway, I don't have a database set up yet, so I don't really have a connection string to supply. Is there any (easy) way to build up a dummy string that has all the necessary parts but won't actually do anything?

Comment: Just use Northwind.mdb or some other demo DB.

Comment: The thing is that I'm doing this to unit test my repository - I don't want to connect to a database at all, just see that the repository gets the correct stuff out of the `Database` object.

Comment: The EF won't connect until you do something which requires it, like new up an ObjectContext and select something. Use SQL Server Profiler to prove this.